# Facebook API calls rate limit reached

Tags: facebook-graph-api

3 days ago we received an alert from the facebook developers page inform us that one of our apps had reached 100% of the hourly rate limit. Our application had an error that caused the increase in calls to the APIS that we solved yesterday afternoon. Since that we deployed the fix we see that in API calls graph (graph: "Application Level Rate Limiting") we don't reach the limit but the calls to the facebook APIS still failing. We want to know if there is a period of time to recover access to the APIs after not reaching that limit.

Here you can see a screenshot of the alert:
[alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYPC5.png)

[image]

In the response headers of one of the calls, we receive this error:

Status code: 403
Header name: WWW-Authenticate
Header value: OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#4) Application request limit reached

[You can see the header here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OojvF.png)

Comment: _“but the calls to the facebook APIS still failing”_ - with the same error, or something else? Have you checked whether the rate limiting headers are present in the response?

Comment: Yes, I get this header: "WWW-Authenticate" with this value: "OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#4) Application request limit reached". The status of the response is a 403

Comment: Yes we are having the same issue. Our application has been running for years and is now being rate limited constantly. Really hope Facebook fixes this bug asap.

Answer (score 1):

You are not the only one right now:
https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/169774397034403/

But i suppose it should be gone after a day or a few hours, in my experience, sometimes i can make a few calls and then it shuts me off again, while our application is not that api call intensive.

Comment: Ok, reading the comments of the attached link I understand that is a bug of facebook that will be solved soon

Comment: When was your app created?

Comment: Our app was made somewhere between 1 and 2 years ago.

Comment: The bug has been open for 30+ days. No end in sight.

Answer (score 0):

This is the response from Facebook:

> Dear all,
>
> We checked with our rate limiting team who confirmed that several
>   improvements were made to help you troubleshoot rate limit related
>   error messages. For example, we've fixed an existing graph and added a
>   new one in the app dashboard to give you more info about the status of
>   your app.
>
> If you continue to receive error code #4 in your request, we'd
>   appreciate it if you can create a new bug report because this thread
>   is getting rather long. We'll be happy to analyze each individual case
>   for you if you can provide the following info:
>
> your app id the entire error message include the trace id a screenshot
>   of the graphs on your app dashboard
>
> Thanks for your patience while we looked into this.
>
> Xiao